# What is this kind of operation called? (Javascript or jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was studying up on some web sites and came across an interesting snippet of code that basically looked like this:

```
   $("#id")["addClass"]("addedClass");
```

I understand what it is doing but what is this operation called? Is it considered **jQuery** or **Javascript**? I haven't seen this before. In the past I would've done something like:

```
 $("#id").addClass("addedClass");
```

Comment: The first is same as second. Object elements can be accessed by `.` operator as well as array brackets notation.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I didn't even know what it was called and therefore stuggled to even begin searching here. Thanks for the link as well.